# Issues in parsing the json data

Tags: android, json

I am developing a android app & have one issue in sloving the JSON parsing. I have less time so I am pasting the JSON. I'd like to know the easiest way to save each filed in array, so that i can use it in a `ListView`.

The JSON is shown below:

```
[{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1444256445",
        "profile_for": "groom",
        "name": "himan",
        "gender": "female",
        "date_of_birth": "1992-07-15 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 23,
    "height": "5.8",
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": "b6.jpg"
},
{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1449242567",
        "profile_for": "bride",
        "name": "ruchi ",
        "gender": "female",
        "date_of_birth": "1992-12-30 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 23,
    "height": "5.8",
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": "i.jpg"
},
{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1449303182",
        "profile_for": "groom",
        "name": "Himanshu Mandloi",
        "gender": "male",
        "date_of_birth": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 2016,
    "height": "5.8",
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": "download.jpg"
},
{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1450940648",
        "profile_for": "groom",
        "name": "abhilash",
        "gender": "male",
        "date_of_birth": "1988-11-11 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 27,
    "height": null,
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1450956081",
        "profile_for": "bride",
        "name": "Hitesh Singhal",
        "gender": "male",
        "date_of_birth": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 2016,
    "height": "5.8",
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1452002747",
        "profile_for": "groom",
        "name": "him",
        "gender": "male",
        "date_of_birth": "1992-02-09 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 24,
    "height": null,
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "matrimony_id": "D1455696296",
        "profile_for": "bride",
        "name": "sunita tripathi",
        "gender": "female",
        "date_of_birth": "1985-05-14 00:00:00",
        "religion": "Hinduism"
    },
    "age": 30,
    "height": null,
    "education": ",",
    "personal": ",,",
    "images": null
}]
```

Comment: Do you have some code implemented?

Comment: your question title is wrong. How you are having issue as you haven't even tried parsing it

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting, what exact problem you are facing. But I have this idea that you are asking about how to use JsonArray in ListView.

Did you try considering it array of json objects, like JsonObject[] array = [your array]

And implement an ArrayAdapter for your list view. You will pass your json array to adapter and adapter will be set in list view.

Comment: There is a JSONArray class... Not JsonObject[]

Comment: Not good solution, though iterating over array can be tried. Or implement a custom adapter which can accept JsonArray object.

Comment: @Jackowski Yeah, I know the Android API. What about it?  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html